# Operation not permitted mkdir \path\\node_modules\\@types\''

Tags: meteor, npm, meteor-packages

I am trying to run the command `npm install --no-bin-links` as part of trying to fix a different issue. The original issue comes from me trying to install the aldeed:simple-schema package, which resulted in an error about a missing simpl-schema (without an e) dependency. I proceeded to run `npm install --save simpl-schema`

My project then proceeded to crash, and give an error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\Code\DB-MM- Test\node_modules\@types'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\Code\DB-MM-Test\node_modules\@types']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\Code\DB-MM-Test\node_modules\@types'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!      path: 'D:\\Code\\DB-MM-Test\\node_modules\\@types' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir \'D:\\Code\\DB-MM-Test\\node_modules\\@types\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Code\\DB-MM-Test\\node_modules\\@types',
npm ERR!   parent: 'DB-MM-Test' }
```

I've looked around online, but couldn't find anything helpful. The only issue that seemed remotely connected was: [This post](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9995)

It seems to me like it's trying to make a directory without a name.

Answer (score 7):

The IDE is probably holding a lock on the file-system object, blocking it from being updated. It worked for me when I closed my IDE.